# How to reversely predict feature values with specified target?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have a problem that seems pretty common in the industry, but I don't know how to solve it in machine learning.

My question is, for example, I have 10 input features  X = (x0, x1, ... x9) and 4 target values Y = (y0, y1, y2, y3).

The number of training/test datasets are small (<1000 items).

In general, I can train the models from X to Y.

But what I want to know is how should I set X, so that I can have some Y values in a specific range (for example y1 > 100).
And the key point is the instance in which y1 > 100 is not in the dataset.

I've tried to do some survey and I found this kind of problem is called the "inverse problem".

But I still don't know how to apply some ML skills, such as SVM, Decision tree, to solve it.

Is anyone has experience in this kind of problem? Could you share with me the way you tackled it?

Comment: Can't you just switch X and Y? Y becomes the input, and X becomes the label. To then get an X for a given Y (let's say Y1 = 100), you give 100 to the model.

Comment: I've tried to reverse it, but my dataset doesn't have the spec I want.  So I figure I would never have a convincing prediction. I've edited the post to mention this problem.

Comment: If Y1 > 100 is not in the dataset, what do we have to go off of? In general if you want to make a prediction for something in a range of values you atleast need some data from that range.

Comment: That exactly my problem is. The dataset is weird.